# exists() does not work but getAbsolutePath() does work

Tags: java

I have the below code whereby I create a File type based on a pre-created file "test.brd" and also call the getAbsolutePath() method on this File, this all works correctly. However, when I run the exists() method, this is deemed as not existing.

When I debug, the status of the File is null and the path is also null, yet the getAbsolutePath() method works. I have debugged and it goes to the Security section of the exists() method.

Please see below:

```
File inputFile = new File("/Users/myname/Desktop/project_name/test.brd");
// The below works and returns the path
System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
if (inputFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Exists");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

Even when I construct the file without the absolute path and just give the file name as a parameter (stored locally with Java file) the correct absolute path is provided.

Hope this makes sense. All I want to do is read a pre-created file into an Array, each character is an element in the array, I was intending on using `scanner` to read the file, but `inputFile` does not exist to be read.

Comment: a file in memory and a file on your drive are not the same thing.

Comment: "whereby I create a File type"... just to be clear `new File(..)` _does not_ create a real file. In fact it doesn't create anything, except an instance of `File`. It does nothing on your hard drive.

Comment: @Tom apologies, the file does exist on my Hard Drive as test.brd, it is in the same directory as the Java project

Comment: so when you call `cat /Users/myname/Desktop/project_name/test.brd` in a console it prints something?

Comment: Does the actual file exist? If not, it's not really unusual that exists() answers false. Im no Java programmer but I guess that getAbsolutePath() returns a path even when the file does not exist.

Comment: @DW_0505 then you'll need to re-check the place where your code is looking for the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods are about different aspects of the file:

- `getAbsolutePath()` is about file name. In a way, this is a "string manipulation method" completely separated from the actual file system
- `exists()` is about the actual file. It checks whether or not the file is present in the file system at the location identified by the given path.

Note that `getAbsolutePath()` and other path manipulation methods of `File` *must* work even without the file or the folder being present in the actual file system. Otherwise, the API would not be able to support file creation, e.g. through `createNewFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), you can find the following sentence

> Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system object such as a file or a directory.

Proving that the instance in memory of a `File` object is not necessarily a real file or directory existing in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

File inputFile = new File("/Users/myname/Desktop/project_name/test.brd");
The line above doesn't create a new File and hence it doesn't exists.
If you want to create a file you can use method `inputFile.createNewFile()`.
The method getAbsolutePath() works on the inputFile object and is completely different from file creation.